# Pygame sprite group won't draw because of error: Source objects must be a suface

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

im having a problem with my 2D Platformer game and when trying to display sprite group, an error message appears saying: Pygame: TypeError: Source objects must be a surface, The problem seems to be around the coins sprite group when trying to draw it to the `self.display_surface` in my code here.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Here is my code for my level.py:

```
import pygame
from support import import_csv_layout, import_cut_graphics
from settings import tile_size
from tiles import Tile, StaticTile, Crate, AnimatedTile

class Level:
    def __init__(self, level_data, surface):
        # general setup
        self.display_surface = surface
        self.world_shift = -5

        # terrain setup
        terrain_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data['terrain'])
        self.terrain_sprites = self.create_tile_group(terrain_layout, 'terrain')

        # grass setup
        grass_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data['grass'])
        self.grass_sprites = self.create_tile_group(grass_layout, 'grass')

        # crates
        crate_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data['crates'])
        self.crate_sprites = self.create_tile_group(crate_layout, 'crates')

        # coins
        coins_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data['coins'])
        self.coin_sprites = self.create_tile_group(coins_layout, 'coins')

    def create_tile_group(self, layout, type):
        sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        for row_index, row in enumerate(layout):
            for col_index, val in enumerate(row):
                if val != '-1':
                    x = col_index * tile_size
                    y = row_index * tile_size

                    if type == 'terrain':
                        terrain_tile_list = import_cut_graphics('../gfx/terrain/terrain_tiles.png')
                        tile_surface = terrain_tile_list[int(val)]
                        sprite = StaticTile(tile_size, x, y, tile_surface)

                    if type == 'grass':
                        grass_tile_list = import_cut_graphics('../gfx/decoration/grass/grass.png')
                        tile_surface = grass_tile_list[int(val)]
                        sprite = StaticTile(tile_size, x, y, tile_surface)

                    if type == 'crates':
                        sprite = Crate(tile_size, x, y)

                    if type == 'coins':
                        sprite = AnimatedTile(tile_size, x, y, '../gfx/coins/gold')

                    sprite_group.add(sprite)

        return sprite_group

    def run(self):
        # run the entire game / level

        # terrain
        self.terrain_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
        self.terrain_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)

        # grass
        self.grass_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
        self.grass_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)

        # crate
        self.crate_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
        self.crate_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)

        # coins
        self.coin_sprites.update(self.world_shift)
        self.coin_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)
```

And Here is the tile.py file: AnimatedTile and SaticTile class:

```
class AnimatedTile(Tile):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y, path):
        super().__init__(size, x, y)
        self.frames = import_folder(path)
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.image = self.frames[self.frame_index]
```

```
class StaticTile(Tile):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y, surface):
        super().__init__(size, x, y)
        self.image = surface
```

Also import folder has a surface variable, so i can't tell if its in here:

```
    surface_list = []

    for _,__, image_files in walk(path):
        for image in image_files:
            full_path = path + '/' + image
            image_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()
            surface_list.append(image)

    return surface_list
```

Crate:

```
class Crate(StaticTile):
    def __init__(self, size, x, y):
        super().__init__(size, x, y, pygame.image.load('../gfx/terrain/crate.png').convert_alpha())
        offset_y = y + size
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft = (x,offset_y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in the code that creates the `surface_list`. You have to append `image_surf` to the `surface_list`, but not `image`:

<s>`surface_list.append(image)`</s>

```py
surface_list.append(image_surf)
```